# RecyclerView in SwipeRefreshLayout not worked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I try use RecyclerView in SwipeRefreshLayout but SwipeRefreshLayout  not worked

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/productsList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I need change?

Comment: Can you please share in detail what is facing issue ?

Comment: what details can there be. I pull the top-down screen, and the loading animation does not appear. Nothing happens. before this was a simple list of everything worked

Comment: of course. even if it was not an animation should appear anyway

Comment: Try to remove ConstraintLayout and check

Comment: Try to set recycler view height as wrap_content and delete constraint_layout .

Answer (score -2):

Try this way `activity_my.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_layout">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and the activity class goes like this `MainActivity`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        refreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_layout);
        refreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW);
        refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

            }
        });

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutParams = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutParams);
        SomeAdapter adapter = new SomeAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(int newState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(int dx, int dy) {
                refreshLayout.setEnabled(layoutParams.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/VladSumtsov/ad4e13511a9b73ff3b13

Comment: its look like crutch. and setOnScrollListener is deprecated

Comment: did u even try it?